# ActionListeners to JComboBox in netbeans

Tags: java

```
import javax.swing.JComboBox;

/*
 * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */

/**
 *
 * @author KN
 */
public class NewJFrame2 extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    /**
     * Creates new form NewJFrame2
     */
    public NewJFrame2() {
        initComponents();
    }

    /**
     * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
     * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
     * regenerated by the Form Editor.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        jPanel1 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
        jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jComboBox1 = new javax.swing.JComboBox();
        jLabel2 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jComboBox2 = new javax.swing.JComboBox();
        jTextField1 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        jSeparator1 = new javax.swing.JSeparator();
        jLabel3 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jTextField2 = new javax.swing.JTextField();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setTitle("CS12MP2: IEEE754");
        setPreferredSize(new java.awt.Dimension(350, 250));

        jPanel1.setPreferredSize(new java.awt.Dimension(300, 300));

        jLabel1.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 0, 14)); // NOI18N
        jLabel1.setText("Convert to:");

        jComboBox1.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 0, 14)); // NOI18N
        jComboBox1.setModel(new javax.swing.DefaultComboBoxModel(new String[] { "DEC", "IEEE" }));
        jComboBox1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jComboBox1ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        jLabel2.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 0, 14)); // NOI18N
        jLabel2.setText("Precision:");

        jComboBox2.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 0, 14)); // NOI18N
        jComboBox2.setModel(new javax.swing.DefaultComboBoxModel(new String[] { "Single", "Double", "L" }));
        jComboBox2.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jComboBox2ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        jTextField1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jTextField1ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        jLabel3.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 0, 14)); // NOI18N
        jLabel3.setText("Output");

        jTextField2.setEditable(false);
        jTextField2.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jTextField2ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        javax.swing.GroupLayout jPanel1Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jPanel1);
        jPanel1.setLayout(jPanel1Layout);
        jPanel1Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, false)
                    .addComponent(jTextField1)
                    .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addComponent(jLabel1)
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                        .addComponent(jComboBox1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 73, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addGap(16, 16, 16)
                        .addComponent(jLabel2)
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                        .addComponent(jComboBox2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                    .addComponent(jSeparator1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING)
                    .addComponent(jLabel3, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 93, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addComponent(jTextField2))
                .addGap(0, 82, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );
        jPanel1Layout.setVerticalGroup(
            jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(jLabel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 47, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addComponent(jComboBox1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addComponent(jLabel2)
                    .addComponent(jComboBox2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                .addComponent(jTextField1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                .addComponent(jSeparator1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 12, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                .addComponent(jLabel3, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 17, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                .addComponent(jTextField2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addGap(0, 140, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addComponent(jPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 380, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addContainerGap())
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(20, 20, 20)
                .addComponent(jPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 280, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>                        

    private void jComboBox1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                           


    }                                          

    private void jComboBox2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                           
        // TODO add your handling code here:
    }                                          

    private void jTextField1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                            
        // TODO add your handling code here:
    }                                           

    private void jTextField2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                            
        // TODO add your handling code here:
    }                                           

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
        //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
        /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
         * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
         */
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame2.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame2.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame2.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame2.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        //</editor-fold>

        /* Create and display the form */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new NewJFrame2().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JComboBox jComboBox1;
    private javax.swing.JComboBox jComboBox2;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel2;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel3;
    private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel1;
    private javax.swing.JSeparator jSeparator1;
    private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField1;
    private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField2;
    // End of variables declaration                   
}
```

How do I add actionListeners to JComboBox? I'm sorry. I am new to the netbeans environment.

Comment: hmmm you already have?

Comment: See `jComboBox1ActionPerformed()`, `jComboBox2ActionPerformed()` functions in your code. There they are.

Answer (score 1):

You already have actionListener added in your code. I think you just need to add the functionality you wanted to implements in the method.

```
private void jComboBox1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                           


}                                          

private void jComboBox2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                           
    // TODO add your handling code here:
}                                          

private void jTextField1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                            
    // TODO add your handling code here:
}                                           

private void jTextField2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                            
    // TODO add your handling code here:
}
```

Apart from that I would highly suggest you to read this [article](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/combobox.html).

Answer (score 1):

This is how:! right click on combo box -> click on Action performed and it will take you to code panel: inside the implemented function [image]

Answer (score 1):

Start by selecting the combo box in the design mode/form view

On the properties tab, select "Events"

[image]

From the "Events" view, you can select the `actionPerformed` property and either type on a new method name, or press the "..." button which will allow you to add new methods that will be called when `actionPerformed` is called, allowing you to supply multiple methods of the single event

[image]

I also believe you can just double click the component and NetBeans will create a default method if none exists and it will take you to the code view of the method (if it existed before or not)

Comment: adding picture is fun, isn't it ? ;)

Comment: @Sage Pictures speak a thousand words ;)